# import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

How do I fix this I want to create a custom login portal in nextjs13 using next-auth?

if I use try to use
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

it tells me to use 'next/navigation'

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EzJn.png)

Help me ;(

Using a custom sign in and sign out is annoying in next-auth

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use usePathName rather than useRouter.
An example from the documentation ([nextjs13 usePathname](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname)) :

```
'use client'
 
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  return <p>Current pathname: {pathname}</p>
}
```

Comment: usePathname is a client-side component so it can't be used at layout.tsx i.e "use client" and "usePathname"

Comment: i am using folder based routing